# Возможны ли одинаковые алиасы в SQL?

Tags: sql, mysql

Например: `NAME AS nm, NAME_BIG as nm`?

Comment: 1. Зачем?
2. Что мешает проверить вручную? Дело двух минут.
3. При определенном желании точно можно получить одинаковые названия столбцов, и потом с этим невозможно работать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет. Имена столбцов должны быть уникальны.